# Handle checked and then unchecked checkbox's value in listview android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, checkbox

In my activity I have 4 items in a list view with checkboxes in each row. After I leave activity I want all the checked item position numbers in an arraylist. This code works fine when user clicks all the checkboxes ones and leave the activity. But when user clicks a checkbox and then unchecks it, item position is arraylist doesnt able to clear. This methood is in my CustomAdapter class.

```
class GameAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
      private ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      public ArrayList<Integer> getPositions() {
          return positions;
      }

      getView(....){
         final ViewHolder holder;
         holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {

                    positions.add(position);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am handling this adapter class in the activity where my listview resides. There I am taking this arraylist values like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> gamePositions = mGameAdapter.getPositions();
String itemNumbers = gamePositions.toString();
```

in itemNumber string I want all the checked item number values.

Thank you in advance for guidance....

Comment: You add the values to your array on check but you never remove them when unchecking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {

  positions.add(position);
}
```

with this

```
 if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
     if(!positions.contains(position))
        positions.add(position);

 } else {
     if(positions.contains(position))
         positions.remove(position);

 }
```

Comment: hello...It worked but now problem is when I click one checkbox and uncheck it it gives "unfortunately app stopped" error but when I check it and uncheck it after checking another checkbox it doesnt....bit of a tongue twister :-P but hope you will understand..if not clear tell me I will describe againn..

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1, this is when I checked second item and unchecked it...

Comment: are you sure that the exception shows one of these lines?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102302/discussion-between-aalap-patel-and-vspallas).

Answer (score 1):

Follow below approach.

- Use HashMap instead of Arraylist, like below

  ```
    HashMap<Integer,Boolean> mapOfSelection = new HashMap<>();
  ```
- before `onClick` method, assign `position` to the checkbox, like below.

  ```
   holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
  ```
- In onClick, do the following.

  ```
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

          mapOfSelection.put((Integer)buttonView.getTag(),isChecked); // True if this position/value is checked, false otherwise.
      }
  ```
- Now when you need the selected items, just loop through the hashmap and check the `positions/Key` which have `True` value.

Comment: I did this but application stops when I uncheck the item.

Comment: Check the answer again, modified it. This is better approach. You will get it resolved.

Comment: YW, make sure you dont stuck with issues with your approach, as arrayList.remove() has two definitions, one for remove(position/Integer) and other as remove(Object), Also you has Object/Value as integer, it can cause issues with large dataset as List will not identify if you are calling Remove for position or for Object.

Comment: yes, I just want to send position numbers as a string in "leagues" named string.

Comment: Sure, be cautious though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102301/discussion-between-aalap-patel-and-aankit).